# for in order to vs. in order to

Tags: idiomatic-language

> According to many philosophers, there is a purely logical reason why science will never be able to explain everything. **For in order to explain something,** whatever it is, we need to
> invoke something else. -Philosophy of Science: Very Short IntroductionSamir Okasha · 2016-

I think For is not necessary, 'For in order to explain something' is idiomatic?

Answer (score 4):

**For** is not part of the phrase **in order to.** Here, it means **because**. It is introducing the sentence as an explanation of what was said in the previous one; the reason why science cannot explain everything.

Comment: We could also reorder the sentence to make this more explicit: "For we need to invoke something else in order to explain something"